# Footer only on last data page in Reportlab

Tags: footer, reportlab

I am working on an invoice and I would like to add a footer on the last page only (which can also be the first page).

Since the data of the table is dynamic, I am not able to calculate the number of pages.

Now I am working with 2 Page Templates, firstpage (with 2 frames and footer1) and nextpages (with 1 frame and footer2). This works when the data fills two pages, but when the table fills only 1 page or more then 2 pages, it no longer works.

I defined the footer in the following way:

```
    footerFrame = Frame(x1=35*mm, y1=20*mm, width=175*mm, height=15*mm)
    footerStory = [ Paragraph("Have a nice day.", styles["fancy"]) ]

    def footer2(canvas,document):
        canvas.saveState()
        footerFrame.addFromList(footerStory, canvas)
        canvas.restoreState()
```

Is there a more flexible way to define a footer, so it only shows up on the page at which the table ends?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

By overriding ReportLabs canvas Class, you CAN keep track of the pages (granted I've done it with other reports that don't involve flowables, but I believe you can still make it work!) .

Since you are using a flowable (Paragraph), you need to know how many pages it is going to be with each new PDF generation (the length is the dynamic part).  I am not 100% positive, but I think ReportLab's flowable still invoke the "showPage()" method of the canvas.  So you can do the following:

In pseudo-code/part-python, I'd recommend the following (untested):

```
class MyFooterCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ## Subclass the ReportLab canvas class.  
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ## Create an empty list to store the saved pages so you can keep track of them.
        self._savedPages = []

    def showPage(self):
        """Override the showPage method"""

        ## We are writing our own showPage() method here, so we can keep track of 
        ## what page we are on.
        self._savedPages.append(self)
        ## Start a new page.
        self._startPage()

    def drawFooter(self):
        """Draws the footer to the page.  You can have it do whatever you want here"""
        self.drawString(50, 50, "This is my footer, yay me - footer freedom")

    def save(self):
        """Saves the entire PDF in one go, a bit costly to do it this way,
           but certainly one way to get a footer."""
        numPages = len(self._savedPages)

        for pages in self._savedPages:
            ## Finds the last page and when it 'hits', it will call the self.drawFooter() method.
            if pages == self._savedPages[-1]:
                self.drawFooter()
            else:
                ## If it's not the last page, explicitly pass over it.  Just being thorough here.
                pass

        ## And... continue doing whatever canvas.Canvas() normally does when it saves.
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)
```

**AGAIN** this is untested, but I think this will give you the behavior you want.  Try it out, if you get stuck let me know, I can hash some of this out if need be, but I've done this same method for other non-flowables and it's worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Your example worked for me as well, thanks. 
There was a little typo of the bracked in the 2nd line after init__.

Comment: @Helga, glad it worked for you!  Thanks for catching that little typo... it should be fixed now.  Also, if you would be so kind as to mark this question as the correct one!  I like getting 'points' :P *self-promoting one SO question at a time!*